# Conditionally replace variable with different variable

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

I haven't been able to find a thread similar to this question, so apologies if it's been asked already.

**I am trying to:**
conditionally replace values of a character variable ("JobCategory_1") with the values in character variable ("JobCategory_2") to create my new variable ("My_Category").

**I have data which looks like:**

```
obs  JobCategory_1                 JobCategory_2      My_Category
1    Business and Administration   Social Sciences     
2    Research and Development      NA
3    Accounting and Finance        Health
4    Admin                         NA
5    Customer Service              Banking
6    Accounting and Finance        Health
7    Languages                     Education
```

**I have a list of jobs in which I'm interested in changing:**

```
NotSectors <- c("Business and Administration", 
                "Business Development", 
                "Consultancy and Training", 
                "Customer Service", 
                "Development and Project Management", 
                "Economics")
```

**I hope to get something like:**

```
obs  JobCategory_1                 JobCategory_2      My_Category
1    Business and Administration   Social Sciences    Social Sciences 
2    Research and Development      NA                 Research and Development
3    Accounting and Finance        Health             Accounting and Finance
4    Admin                         NA                 Admin
5    Customer Service              Banking            Banking
6    Customer Service              NA                 NA
7    Economics                     Education          Education
```

**Here's the code I've tried:**

```
NewDf <- OldDf %>% 
  mutate(My_Category = "") %>%
  mutate(My_Category = ifelse(JobCategory_1 %in% NotSectors, JobCategory_2, JobCategory_1))
```

... which replaces the right values, but returns numbers instead of the correct char strings

Do you have any tips to do this most efficiently? I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your `JobCategory_1` and  `JobCategory_2` might be factors. You can try to define the variables as characters: `NewDf <- OldDf %>%   mutate(My_Category = ifelse(JobCategory_1 %in% NotSectors, as.character(JobCategory_2), as.character(JobCategory_1)))`

Comment: The columns that you have are factors, try to turn them to characters and your code should work. `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.character)`. Also you don't need `mutate(My_Category = "") %>%` in your code.

Comment: @tamtam and Ronak Shah, many thanks - your solutions and tips worked as well. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Now I used your last dataframe as example and it works!
Explanation: case_when is a function from dplyr package that allows you to vectorise multiple if_else() statements.

```
mutate(My_category=case_when(JobCategory_1 %in% NotSectors ~ JobCategory_2, 
TRUE ~ JobCategory_1))
```

The above code chunk means: make a new column My_category then
if characters from NotSectors are in column JobCategory_1 then replace by characters from JobCategory_2, else take the character from JobCategory_1 (do not replace).

```
NotSectors <- c("Business and Administration", 
                "Business Development", 
                "Consultancy and Training", 
                "Customer Service", 
                "Development and Project Management", 
                "Economics")

df <- tribble(
 ~obs, ~JobCategory_1, ~JobCategory_2, 
1, "Business and Administration", "Social Sciences", 
2, "Research and Development", NA, 
3, "Accounting and Finance", "Health", 
4, "Admin", NA, 
5, "Customer Service", "Banking", 
6, "Customer Service", NA, 
7, "Economics", "Education")

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(My_category=case_when(JobCategory_1 %in% NotSectors ~ JobCategory_2,
                               TRUE ~ JobCategory_1))
```

edit:
[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Any way you could could explain what this essentially means in English? The help(case_when) doesn't provide much info regarding your syntax. Also, the solution works, however, in my df the code grabs "Accounting and Finance" as well, but instead of changing it to "Health" it records an NA. So far, it is only Accounting and Finance that I've noticed. I see it works properly for you.

Comment: See my edit. I now have used the correct dataframe (desired). It works.